# Kotlin + Moxy. Получаю ошибку в сгенерированном методе getViewState

Tags: android, kotlin, moxy

Всем привет.

Изучаю Kotlin и Moxy под Android.

Во время сборки проекта, студия выдает ошибку:

Calculator\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\com\strikalov\calculator\Presenter\MainPresenter$$ViewStateProvider.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
import com.strikalov.calculator.Presenter;

Ругается на файл, который библиотека Moxy, на сколько я понимаю, сама генерирует. А именно на класс Presenter:

```
import com.arellomobile.mvp.MvpView;
import com.arellomobile.mvp.ViewStateProvider;
import com.arellomobile.mvp.viewstate.MvpViewState;
import com.strikalov.calculator.Presenter; // <- Вот здесь ругается
import java.lang.Override;

public class MainPresenter$$ViewStateProvider extends ViewStateProvider {
    @Override
    public MvpViewState<? extends MvpView> getViewState() {
        return new Presenter.MainView$$State();
    }
}
```

Посмотрел работающий проект Java + Moxy, там в аналогичном класса указано следующее:

```
public class MainPresenter$$ViewStateProvider extends ViewStateProvider {
    @Override
    public MvpViewState<? extends MvpView> getViewState() {
        return new MainView$$State();
    }
}
```

Никакого класса Presenter там нет, а в проекте Kotlin он почему-то подставляется сам и на него же ругается. Может это как-то связано с kapt kotlin?

Подскажите, что я делаю не так, что нужно исправить, чтобы заработало. Спасибо

Код view:

```
import com.arellomobile.mvp.MvpView

interface MainView : MvpView {

    fun test()

}
```

Код презентара:

```
import com.arellomobile.mvp.InjectViewState
import com.arellomobile.mvp.MvpPresenter
import com.strikalov.calculator.Model.interactors.CalculatorInteractor

@InjectViewState
class MainPresenter(val calculatorInteractor: CalculatorInteractor): MvpPresenter<MainView>() {


}
```

Код активити:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import com.arellomobile.mvp.MvpAppCompatActivity
import com.arellomobile.mvp.presenter.InjectPresenter
import com.arellomobile.mvp.presenter.ProvidePresenter
import com.strikalov.calculator.App
import com.strikalov.calculator.Model.interactors.CalculatorInteractor
import com.strikalov.calculator.Presenter.MainPresenter
import com.strikalov.calculator.Presenter.MainView
import com.strikalov.calculator.R
import javax.inject.Inject

class MainActivity : MvpAppCompatActivity(), MainView {

    @Inject
    lateinit var calculatorInteractor: CalculatorInteractor

    @InjectPresenter
    lateinit var mainPresenter: MainPresenter

    private lateinit var textResult: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        App.getAppComponent().injectMainActivity(this)

    }

    @ProvidePresenter
    fun providePresenter() = MainPresenter(calculatorInteractor)

    override fun test() {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

Файл gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.strikalov.calculator"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.4'

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.21'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.21'

    implementation 'com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.5'
    kapt 'com.arello-mobile:moxy-compiler:1.5.5'
    implementation 'com.arello-mobile:moxy-android:1.5.5'
    implementation 'com.arello-mobile:moxy-app-compat:1.5.5'


}
```

Comment: Приведите код презентера, вью и фрагмента/активити, это вью реализующими в вопросе. Возможно вы аннотации как-то не так указали. Ссылки на github недостаточно - вы там код поменяете и вопрос потеряет смысл

Comment: 1.5.5 нестабильная версия, поменяйте на 1.5.3

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо за комментарии.

Мне помогло заменить kapt на annotationProcessor - только для библиотеки moxy

```
implementation 'com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.5'
annotationProcessor 'com.arello-mobile:moxy-compiler:1.5.5'
implementation 'com.arello-mobile:moxy-android:1.5.5'
implementation 'com.arello-mobile:moxy-app-compat:1.5.5'
```

Comment: а как ты собирался генерить без включенного анотации процесса, глупая ошибка

Comment: вообще я рассчитывал что kapt выполнит его работу, т.к. в примерах везде показан kapt а не annotationProcessor